# How to get simple margins of 2cm?

Tags: margins

I have been trying for several days to get simple margins like a Word Document. I have started to learn latex 1 month ago, so Im not very familiar with its strange margins !!
Anyways, I would like to get a simple page with 2cm of margins.

```
    \documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

        \definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
        \makeatletter
        \newlength\dlf@normtxtw
        \setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
        \def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
        \newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
        \newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
          \sbox\feline@chapter{%
            \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
              \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
            }}%
          \rotatebox{90}{%
            \resizebox{%
              \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
          \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
        }
        \newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
          \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
          \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
            \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
          }}
        \makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
          \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
          \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
          \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
          \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
          \renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
          \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
          \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
        }
        \makeatother
        \chapterstyle{daleif1}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


    \geometry{
    a4paper,
    right=2cm,
    left=2cm,
    nomarginpar,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=20mm
    }
    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Test chapter}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{document
}
```

[image]

However, I don't have a right-margin and left-margin of 2 cm when I print my file.

It makes me so furious ! I don't understand why it doesn't work. The rightmargin is longer than the left-margin, so I guess there is still a kind of margin on the right. Yet, I have already removed the marginpar...

Does anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Edit : 
I got : rightmargin = 1.8cm, leftmargin = 2.2cm, textwidth = 17cm

Comment: In my experiment I get 2cm on all four sides. I'm inclined to think that you're getting US Letter sized paper. Can you check the information in the PDF viewer? Are you doing `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or directly `pdflatex`?

Comment: In Evince (ubuntu), I can see "A4 paper". Im using XeLatex.
Maybe it is my printer ?

Comment: Sometimes printers have the tendency of reducing the page to fit; usually Adobe Reader thinks A4 paper doesn't fit on A4 paper, so it applies a 5% reduction

Comment: Yeah, but it is stil strange because my right-margin = 1.8cm and my leftmargin = 2.2cm...

Comment: @TexisHard `pdflatex testpage` with `a4paper` as first answer gets you a test page for A4 for testing the printing process.

Comment: @TexisHard I tried again, adding some rules in the margins; all the margins are 2cm exactly; I tested with rules 1.95cm long, in order to see a small gap at the end, which is indeed visible on all four sides. As Heiko suggests, it may be a problem in communication with your printer. In this case adding `\setlength{\hoffset}{0.2mm}` just after `\begin{document}` might solve the problem. I should remark that 2cm on all four sides doesn't seem a good book format (but I understand you could be forced to use it).

Comment: OK. I run pdflatex testpage with a4paper and I got :
rightmargin : 2.3cm / leftmargin = 2.70cm. (1inch = 2.54cm).